# Shifts-induced group of a toroidal cube

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Consider $[n]^d$ -- a $d$-dimensional toroidal cube with side length $n$ divided into $n^d$ unit cubes. Define $k$-shift as a following permutation type on unit cubes: choose $S \subset [n]$ with $|S| = k$, $i \in S$, and assign a number $y_j \in [n]$ to every $j \not \in S$. For a unit cube $(x_1, \ldots, x_d)$, we change $x_i$ to $x_i + 1$ with looping over the edge if $x_j = y_j$ for every $j \not \in S$, otherwise the cube stays in place. For instance, a $1$-shift in a toroidal square would be cyclic shift of a row or a column, a $2$-shift in a toroidal 3D cube is a shift of a planar layer, and so on.

Let $G_d(n, k)$ be the group induced by all possible $k$-shifts in $[n]^d$. This question is concerned with identifying $G_d(n, k)$, or at least some of its properties.

1. In which cases can one identify $G_d(n, k)$? What is its size, simple subgroups, composition series?
2. Clearly, for any $k \in [d - 1]$ we have that $G_d(n, k + 1)$ is a subgroup $G_d(n, k)$. Can we answer some of the questions above about $G_d(n, k) / G_d(n, k + 1)$? Are there $n, k, d$ such that the quotient above is trivial?
3. Given a permutation $\sigma \in \mathrm{Sym}([n]^d)$, can one efficiently determine the highest $k$ such that $\sigma \in G_d(n, k)$?

Choice of $n$ is not particularly important, for simplicity we may take $n$ to be a prime number.

Comment: "induced by": you mean "generated by"? $G_d(n,k+1)$ is a priori not a normal subgroup of $G_d(n,k)$, so the quotient is not a group, in particular "the questions above about" this quotient don't make sense a priori.